# Understanding type deduction through std::is_same

Tags: templates, c++11, stl, stdtuple, type-deduction

I want to have a `std::tuple` of a specific size and also provide a function that takes as many arguments as the tuple and of the same exact types.

I thought I could use a variadic template function to construct a tuple from the parameter pack and compare the two tuples with `std::is_same`

Here is some sample code to further explain what I' ve tried

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

static const auto TupleInts =
     std::make_tuple(
        1,
        2,
        3
    );

static const auto TuplePairs =
    std::make_tuple(
        std::make_pair(1, 1),
        std::make_pair(2, 2),
        std::make_pair(3, 3)
    );

typedef decltype(TupleInts) TupleIntsType;
typedef decltype(TuplePairs) TuplePairsType;
typedef std::tuple<int, int, int> TupleType;

template<typename... Ts>
bool compare(Ts... vals) {
    std::cout << typeid(std::tuple<Ts...>).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(TupleType).name() << std::endl;

    return std::is_same < std::tuple<Ts...>, TupleType >::value;
}

template<typename... Ts>
bool comparePairsTuple(Ts... vals) {
    std::cout << typeid(std::tuple<std::pair<int, Ts>...>).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(TuplePairsType).name() << std::endl;

    return std::is_same < std::tuple<std::pair<int, Ts>...>, TuplePairsType >::value;
}

template<typename... Ts>
bool compareIntsTuple(Ts... vals) {
        std::cout << typeid(std::tuple<Ts...>).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(TupleIntsType).name() << std::endl;

    return std::is_same < std::tuple<Ts...>, TupleIntsType >::value;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << comparePairsTuple(1, 2, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << compareIntsTuple(1, 2, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << compare(1, 2, 3) << std::endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

This is what I get under Visual Studio 2013(vc120)

```
class std::tuple<struct std::pair<int,int>,struct std::pair<int,int>,struct std::pair<int,int> >
class std::tuple<struct std::pair<int,int>,struct std::pair<int,int>,struct std::pair<int,int> >
0
class std::tuple<int,int,int>
class std::tuple<int,int,int>
0
class std::tuple<int,int,int>
class std::tuple<int,int,int>
1
```

and under GCC 5.2.0

```
St5tupleIJSt4pairIiiES1_S1_EE
St5tupleIJSt4pairIiiES1_S1_EE
0
St5tupleIJiiiEE
St5tupleIJiiiEE
0
St5tupleIJiiiEE
St5tupleIJiiiEE
1
```

Why are the first two is_same `false` and the last one `true`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first two cases the types that you compare using **std::is_same** have different const qualifications. **std::is_same** gives true only if given types are the same and they have the same const-volatile qualifications. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same

For example:

```
static const auto TupleInts =
     std::make_tuple(
        1,
        2,
        3
    );

typedef decltype(TupleInts) TupleIntsType;

template<typename... Ts>
bool compareIntsTuple(Ts... vals) {
        std::cout << typeid(std::tuple<Ts...>).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(TupleIntsType).name() << std::endl;

    return std::is_same < std::tuple<Ts...>, TupleIntsType >::value;
}
```

**TupleInts** is declared as **const** and in function **compareIntsTuple** it is compared to **std::tuple** which isn't const.

Answer (score 0):

`typeid` discards top-level cv-qualifiers, `std::is_same` does not.

To make it work, add `const` to one or both arguments of `is_same`:

```
return std::is_same <const std::tuple<std::pair<int, Ts>...>,
                     const TuplePairsType >::value;
```